# Присоединительное предложение в придаточном предложении или вставка ко всему предложению?

Tags: вставка

В видеоролике мужчина, похожий на А-ва -- его играет финский актер Кари Кетонен, -- перекраивает карту.

или убрать второе тире:

В видеоролике мужчина, похожий на А-ва -- его играет финский актер Кари Кетонен, перекраивает карту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы заменила тире на скобки, так конструкция будет лучше смотреться:
В видеоролике мужчина, похожий на А-ва( его играет финский актер Кари Кетонен), перекраивает карту.

Вставная конструкция поясняет состав подлежащего,видимо, актёр похож на А-ва.

Answer (score 1):

Второе тире не ставится:

В видеоролике мужчина, похожий на А-ва, - его играет финский актер Кари Кетонен - перекраивает карту.

Перед вставкой находится обособленный оборот, которые  не входят в состав вставки.

Похожий пример:

День, который она провела в Москве, – потом она часто вспоминала об этом – был тёплым, солнечным.

Comment: Vera, Вы пишете: "Второе тире не ставится", а сами ставите. Как понять? Может, Вы про запятую?

Comment: Да, спасибо,  ЗАПЯТАЯ не ставится. Вставка, в отличие от приложения, всегда выделяется тире с дух сторон, она свой вставочный статус не изменяет. Обсуждается только количество запятых, а это зависит от различных факторов: от наличия обособленных оборотов на границе вставки, от того, относится ли вставка к первой части высказывания.

Answer (score 1):

В видеоролике мужчина, похожий на А-ва, -- его играет финский актер Кари Кетонен -- перекраивает карту. Я бы так расставила знаки препинания. Похожий на А-ва- это обособленное определение, запятые с обеих сторон. Тире с обеих сторон как дополнительное пояснение. запятая после Кетонен не нужна, так как Мужчина перекраивает карту- это главные члены предложения, а их запятыми друг от друга не отделяют.